# Supertype casting in generics (Getting the generic supertype of a generic type)

Tags: java, generics

This is a simplified sample of what I'm trying to do using **Java Generics**.

```
void <T> recursiveMethod(T input) {
    //do something with input treating it as type T
    if (/*need to check if T has a supertype*/) {
        recursiveMethod((/*need to get supertype of T*/) input);

        // NOTE that I am trying to call recursiveMethod() with
        // the input object cast as immediate supertype of T.
        // I am not trying to call it with the class of its supertype.
        // Some of you seem to not understand this distinction.
    }
}
```

If we have a long chain of types *A extends B extends C (extends Object)*, calling `recursiveMethod(new A())` should execute as follows:

```
recursiveMethod(A input)
 -> A has supertype B
recursiveMethod(B input)
 -> B has supertype C
recursiveMethod(C input)
 -> C has supertype Object
recursiveMethod(Object input)
 -> Object has no supertype -> STOP
```

I am **able to do it *without* Generics** as follows:

```
void recursiveMethod(Object input) {
    recursiveMethod(input.getClass(), input);
    }
}

private void recursiveMethod(Class cls, Object input) {
    //do something with input treating it as class 'cls'
    if (cls != null) {
        recursiveMethod(cls.getSuperclass(), input);
    }
}
```

**Can I do the same using Generics?** I have tried declaring as `<S, T extends S>`, then casting as `(S)input` but `S` is always equal to `T` and it results in *stack overflow*.

Comment: did you consider to do `input.getClass().getSuperClass()`

Comment: Think you misunderstood the question user902383 :)

Comment: nope, i just gave you a hint, not solution, if you applied this to your `recursiveMethod` you would have our solution

Comment: @user902383 good try, but again, you misunderstood the question. I don't want to pass the supertype `Class` object into the `recursiveMethod`, I want to pass the `input` object cast as its supertype (**and do this in Generics** - that is the real issue). Two very different things. Anyway I have favoured the iterative method by sp00m which works great while this recursive approach doesn't work at all. So, no point trying to explain any further. `=)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an iterative approach that could solve your problem:

```
public static <T> void iterateOverSupertypes(T input) {
    Class<?> clazz = input.getClass();
    while (clazz.getSuperclass() != null) {
        clazz = clazz.getSuperclass();
    }
}
```

Comment: Very interesting! I didn't think of iteration! `=)`

Comment: What is the point of iteration if you don 't call the method in it?

Comment: Note that there's no reason for the method to be generic.

Comment: @Paul for this simple example, you're right. But my real application has more than one input arguments, and I want to lock them all into one generic type T (so that random objects aren't passed into it by bad coders; if they do, it will degrade the method to using `Object` type).

Comment: @ADTC What's your actual method signature? It may not constrain arguments the way you expect. For example, declaring `(T input1, T input2)` would be pointless since `T` can just resolve to its upper bound, `Object`.

Comment: _"declaring (T input1, T input2) would be pointless since T can just resolve to its upper bound, Object"_ It wouldn't be completely pointless. Yes as I said in my comment, it will degrade to the `Object` type. I know this kinda goes against the principles of _type safety_, but my intention is to use it as a warning geared towards programmers using the method (since we can see in the IDE what type the method is degrading to, and if it degrades to `Object`, we can remove it since there's no point in calling the method).

Comment: Anyway I came with a problem and got a solution. I don't see why we should be discussing about the point of things I'm trying to achieve. `=)`

Comment: @ADTC I thought I'd ask since I've seen enough people get tripped up thinking a method taking two `T`s will enforce them to be e.g. `Integer` and `Integer`. Of course that's a misunderstanding of how inheritance works. I'd recommend having the method also take a `Class<T>` in order to actually enforce what you want. But you're obviously free to do what you please.

Comment: I concur about the misunderstanding. Anyway `Class<T>` is not what I need because I need the actual object in the method, not just the class of it (_the code in question is quite simplified and doesn't reveal the actual purpose_). Besides, wouldn't it degrade to `Class<Object>`? `=D`

Answer (score 2):

When you create a new A and pass it around in your code your object will always remain an A no matter what you do.

Things like casting and generics are only ways of telling the compiler what class of object you are expecting but don't change the object's behaviour in any way. So I don't see what you're trying to achieve by "treating it as type T", but the only way to achieve this that I can see is to pass the type along like you did in your example without generics.

P.S.: Always remember: Java generics are just some way for the compiler to ensure type-safety, but there won't be any trace of them in the compiled code!!!!